# MySQL Trigger - Query 3rd table before inserting

Tags: mysql, database

Firstly, apologies if this post is incomplete or poorly formatted. Newbie behind the wheel.

I have 3 tables involved in this particular challenge (MySQL v5.6).

'bet', 'bet_win' and 'bet_win_cfg'

'bet' and 'bet_win' are identical tables (all the attributes are listed in the 'insert into' statement at the bottom of this post), whilst below is a sample of the 'bet_win_cfg' table

```
INSERT INTO bet_win_cfg (eventVenue, priceRangeMin, priceRangeMax, sizeMin)
VALUES 
("Bairnsdale",2,3,1500),
("Bairnsdale",3.01,4,1400),
("Bairnsdale",4.01,5,1300),
("Bairnsdale",5.01,6,1200),
("Bairnsdale",6.01,7,1000),
("Bairnsdale",7.01,8,800),
("Bairnsdale",8.01,9,700),
("Bairnsdale",9.01,10,600),
("Bairnsdale",10.01,12,500),
("Bairnsdale",12.01,16,450),
("Bairnsdale",16.01,20,400),
("Bairnsdale",20.01,30,300),
("Bairnsdale",30.01,50,250),
("Bairnsdale",50.01,500,200),
("Randwick",30.01,50,250),
("Randwick",50.01,500,200);
etc
```

I have setup an insert trigger on 'bet'. I need to compare 3 values ('bet.eventVenue','bet.price' and 'bet.size') from each new record in the bet table, against the relevant fields in the 'bet_win_cfg' table (eventVenue, priceRangeMin, priceRangeMax, sizeMin) to see if a condition is met (basically every event venue has a minimum Size that needs to be met for each 'price range'. If that minimum bet.size is achieved in it's corresponding price range, I want to insert an identical record into the bet_win table).

For example - A new 'bet' record at Bairnsdale of a size of 1700 for a price of 2.50 would also generate an insert into the bet_win table whilst a bet size of 1400 for a price of 2.50 wouldn't.

There is no error when I create the trigger below. It's just that no records make it into the bet_win table.

So far I have the following:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ins_LoadBet_win;
delimiter $$
CREATE DEFINER =`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER ins_LoadBet_win BEFORE INSERT ON bet
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE Size_ INT(11);

Select sizeMin INTO Size_ FROM bet_win_cfg
INNER JOIN bet ON bet_win_cfg.eventVenue = bet.eventVenue where bet.price       
BETWEEN bet_win_cfg.priceRangeMin AND bet_win_cfg.priceRangeMax
LIMIT 1;
IF(Size_ < new.Size) THEN
insert into bet_win
(
 id
,exchangeID
,dateTime
,eventVenue
,eventName
,marketName
,marketId
,cfgMarketId
,selectionId
,runnerName
,price
,Size
,TLsize
,RMC
,minPrice
,maxPrice
,A
,B
,availableToLay
,tradedVolume
,cfgAlgorithmId
,betId
,betType
,betStake
,result
,profit
,category
) 
values 
(
 New.id
,New.exchangeID
,New.dateTime
,New.eventVenue
,New.eventName
,New.marketName
,New.marketId
,New.cfgMarketId
,New.selectionId
,New.runnerName
,New.price
,New.Size
,New.TLsize
,New.RMC
,New.minPrice
,New.maxPrice
,New.A
,New.B
,New.availableToLay
,New.tradedVolume
,New.cfgAlgorithmId
,New.betId
,New.betType
,New.betStake
,New.result
,New.profit
,New.category
);
END IF;
END$$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is the first query:

```
Select bwc.sizeMin INTO Size_
FROM bet_win_cfg bwc INNER JOIN
     bet b
     ON bwc.eventVenue = b.eventVenue
where b.price BETWEEN bwc.priceRangeMin AND bwc.priceRangeMax
LIMIT 1;
```

I don't see `new` anywhere.  I think this is what you want:

```
Select bwc.sizeMin INTO Size_
FROM bet_win_cfg bwc
where bwc.eventVenue = new.eventVenue and
      new.price BETWEEN bwc.priceRangeMin AND bwc.priceRangeMax
LIMIT 1;
```

Your original just picks up an arbitrary row from the win cfg table, and that probably has a very large size.